# I can't uninstall modules with Drush master-branch and almost no data on Google

Tags: drush, 8

When navigating to my sites' folder and typing `drush pmu admin_menu` or otherwise `drush pm-uninstall admin_menu` in drush master branch I get:

> Command pm-uninstall needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will
>   need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run
>   this command.

I found only 3 discussions in Google, touching this in relation to Drupal 7 (dev or fresh).

- I should note that another command, drush cr (cache-rebuild) works
  just fine.

### Drush status:

```
C:\wamp\www\sname>drush status
 Drupal version         :  8.0.0
 Site URI               :  http://default
 Database driver        :  mysql
 Database hostname      :  localhost
 Database port          :  3306
 Database username      :  sname
 Database name          :  sname
 PHP executable         :  php.exe
 PHP configuration      :  C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini
 PHP OS                 :  WINNT
 Drush script           :  C:\drush-master\drush.php
 Drush version          :  8.1-dev
 Drush temp directory   :  C:\Users\Beni\AppData\Local\Temp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :
 Drupal root            :  C:\wamp\www\sname
 Site path              :  sites/default
 Sync config path       :  sites/default/files/config_mkuaR5uFQ7VCjh1_FFBuZzWXkUsz-sA7Klv4HO_2yLJG33wfJJabdavO7QKzyIRWiQoWA3IJbg/sync
```

C:\wamp\www\sname>

### Drush sql-conf

```
C:\wamp\www\sname>drush sql-conf
Array
(
[database] => sname
[username] => sname
[prefix] => Array
    (
        [default] =>
    )

[host] => localhost
[port] => 3306
[namespace] => Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql
[driver] => mysql
```

Comment: what is the exact output of `drush cr` ?

Comment: Cache rebuild complete. [ok]

Comment: Post the output of `drush status` and `drush sql-conf`. The error message you are seeing means that Drush cannot find the configuration for your Drupal site. You should run Drush from the same folder that settings.php is located in.

Comment: Updated. I always run Drush from the sites' folder... Is there a different heuristic for Drupal 8?

Comment: try adding --uri=yoursite.url

Comment: Tried, got a very long chart of data; When I ran drush pmu admin_menu afterwards I again got the error "Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with Drush is with admin_menu. This is a bug on admin_menu not been ready. See more about this - [admin_menu has broken d8-beta11 and i cant pm-uninstall](https://www.drupal.org/node/2511214)

How to solve it ?

> (note, deleting the module rm -r modules/admin_menu and rebuilding
>   cache brings the site back)

[Source](https://www.drupal.org/node/2275025#comment-9341733)

**Steps by Step Instructions**

- Open your terminal
- Change directory to you root Drupal 8 core
- Then remove the admin_menu project and then clear the cache.
- `rm -rf modules/admin_menu # Remove the directory.`
- `drush cr # This will clear the cache`

admin_menu is not ready, I will recommend you to use admin_toolbar for now.

Comment: Hi! What is rm -r? What it stands for?

Comment: `rm -rf` is to remove a file and/or directory on a unix terminal (linux and mac will work too) See more about this at http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rm1.html . All you need to do is to remove the admin_menu project from your modules/ folder and clear the cache.

Comment: You wrote in the answer rm -r but here rm -rf, so what is the right form of the two? When I typed at Drush now "drush rm -r admin menu" or "drush rm -rf admin_menu" nothing happened... :| What is the syntax you would use? Thanks!!!

Comment: This is a terminal `rm -rf` they will do the same functionality, which is remove the directory. This command IS NOT A DRUSH COMMAND. `rm -rf` is a terminal command.

Comment: I have added the step by steps instructions on how to do it.

Comment: Oh, I use Windows, I have yet to learn Unix terminal commands.

Comment: If I can't do it with Drush I'll do it manually, and then type drush cr (cache rebuild).

Comment: Just remove the folder admin_menu and clear the cache.